# Behavioral difference between pytest code and real flask session for a route

Tags: python, flask, pytest, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following simple pytest case, which tests a delete operation:

```
def test_delete_club(client, systemAdmin, operationalCountry1, club1):
    rv = loginTo(client, '/admin/clubs/1', '+00000000000','testpassword')
    decodedRv = rv.data.decode('utf-8')
    assert '<td>testClub1</td>' in decodedRv
    rv = client.get('/admin/delete_club/1', follow_redirects = True)
    decodedRv = rv.data.decode('utf-8')
    assert '<td>testClub1</td>' not in decodedRv
    #ensure club1 does not exist in the database either
    c = Club.query.get(1)
    assert c is None
    # make sure club roles are deleted along with the club
    clubRoles = Role.query.filter(Role.club_id == club1.id).all()
    assert len(clubRoles)
```

Basically, it hits the delete URL (`/admin/delete_club/1`) and after following redirects, it asserts that there is neither such a club nor any roles associated with that club in the database.

I am using TDD (test driven development). So I wrote the above test case before the relevant routing code. My route method looks like this:

```
@flaskApp.route('/admin/delete_club/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def delete_club(id):
    '''Deletes the club identified by the id'''
    if not isCurrentUserSysAdmin():
        #TODO better error handling
        return 'you can not touch this'

    clubToDelete = Club.query.get_or_404(id)
    logging.debug('About to delete club: {}'.format(clubToDelete))
    opCountryId = clubToDelete.operationalcountry_id
    try:
        db.session.delete(clubToDelete)
        logging.debug('Deleted club: {}'.format(clubToDelete))
    except:
        flash('Error deleting club')
        logging.error('Error deleting club. Club Details: {}'.format(clubToDelete))
    return redirect(url_for('clubs', countryid = opCountryId))
```

Well, so far so good. Test case passed without a glitch. I was happy. I wanted to give it a go on the real web page. Then I noticed that, although the delete operation had succeeded, on the redirected page, the club I was trying to delete would still be present.

**Then I found the BUG** : I simply forgot to add `db.session.commit()` after deleting the club instance entity. That change fixed the web page.

However, I am still puzzled why my test case does not complain about it and how come it does not fail at all? **Again, test case works without the commit statement**.

Any ideas from more seasoned Flask/Python developers?

Answer (score 0):

In short, `db.session.delete` register transaction into memory to execute. But without `db.commit` that wouldn't execute a query on the database. This method will change only the local representation of databaes. What I recommend you is to use context manager `with session.begin()`.

Comment: As I said, I found and fixed the bug by adding db.session.commit() after the delete statment. However, your answer does NOT shed any light onto why the test case worked, without the commit statement.

Comment: I mean, I don't know what is behind DB. But there could be a few possibilities like fixture scope, maybe some DB settings, maybe some flag of SQL alchemy in pytest to auto-commit scope.

Comment: Scopes of my fixtures are all at function level except client. DB settings could make a difference as I use PostgreSQL for wannabe-production and SQLite (in memory) for development. I will take a closer look at those. Thanks for pointing out. **Could you elaborate a bit on SQL Alchemy in pytest to autocommit scope?** This piece didn't ring a bell.